# How to make the text of a scroll view start at the bottom and work it's way up?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm trying to make a texting application and I want the text to start at the bottom and work it's way up instead of vice versa.    I've tried ScrollView.Focus_UP AND down and text alignment end.  But it's not working.  Why?  Again, Sorry if this is a repost.  I couldn't find anything on it, maybe I'm wording my question wrong.

```
<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/outputScrollView"

    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"  >
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relchatlay"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/outputTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
        android:paddingRight="5dp" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

        />
    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>


public void onSendClicked(View view){
    outputScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    outputScrollView.setTextAlignment(ScrollView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TEXT_START);
    theClient.sendChat(inputEditText.getText().toString());
    inputEditText.setText("");
```

Comment: Does it have to be a scroll view? Could you use a RecyclerView and scroll it to the last entry?

Comment: What is it supposed to be for? Those message bubbles start on top and end on bottom, right?

Comment: @user2875404 that's what it's doing yes.  But I want it to start at the bottom and work it's way up like a regular text messaging app

Comment: Sorry mate but can you rephrase your question? I really think I can help you but I quite don't understand what you are asking for. If I add a textView to another view, it usually spawns at the bottom. What happens to outputTextView? Are you just editing the text of the textView statically? Think about writing a custom view that you can keep on adding for each message. This is most likely how it's done in established apps.

Comment: @user2875404  what I want it to do is start the text at the bottom of the scroll view and work its way up when another message is sent into the scroll view.  Basically putting the old message at the above the new one, but aligning the new message right above the inputTextView.  instead it starts at the top of the scroll view and works its way down the scroll view.

Comment: Aight. Wrap a layout (easiest here would be a table) in the scrollview. You can create a new row for every message. This way you can make sure it will always spawn at the bottom. You can also use e.g. LinearLayout but TableLayout should be fine.

Comment: @user2875404 How would i push it to the bottom with a table layout?

Comment: TableRow tr = new TableRow(this); Always. Goes. To. The. Bottom.

Comment: @user2875404 I was trying to do it through xml

Comment: that's not efficient code. How would the phone know, how many messages there will be in every conversation?